# Replacing array at i`th dimension

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a two-dimensional array

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]])
```

and I would like to replace the third vector (in the second dimension) with zeros. I would do

```
a[:, 2] = np.array([0, 0, 0])
```

But what if I would like to be able to do that programmatically? I mean, let's say that variable `x = 1` contained the dimension on which I wanted to do the replacing. How would the function `replace(arr, dimension, value, arr_to_be_replaced)` have to look if I wanted to call it as `replace(a, x, 2, np.array([0, 0, 0])`?

`numpy` has a similar function, `insert`. However, it doesn't replace at dimension `i`, it returns a copy with an additional vector.

*All solutions are welcome, but I do prefer a solution that doesn't recreate the array as to save memory.*

Comment: Why will `a[:, x] = np.array([0, 0, 0])` not suffice ?

Comment: @mujjiga I fixed the example so that it was in line with what I had in mind.

Comment: @FooBar your array is not large enough for an index value of `2`, maybe pick `0`? :-)

Comment: @NilsWerner I also extended the example array so it actually does work. Sorry for the messiness, I wanted to not have the same number for dimension and index and I didnt think of `0`.

Comment: Ah right, I'll adjust my answer

Comment: Does `np.put` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
arr[:, 1]
```

is basically shorthand for

```py
arr[(slice(None), 1)]
```

that is, a `tuple` with `slice` elements and integers.

Knowing that, you can construct a tuple of `slice` objects manually, adjust the values depending on an `axis` parameter and use that as your index. So for

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]])

axis = 1
idx = 2
arr[:, idx] = np.array([0, 0, 0])
#      ^- axis position
```

you can use

```py
slices = [slice(None)] * arr.ndim
slices[axis] = idx
arr[tuple(slices)] = np.array([0, 0, 0])
```